# Can't get React Router to work in my React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get a button to route to a specific component and it just does nothing but change the address in the navbar.

Here's my index.js file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import {
      createBrowserRouter,
      createRoutesFromElements,
      Route,
      RouterProvider
    } from 'react-router-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import Email from './screens/Email';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    const router = createBrowserRouter(
      createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
          <Route path="email" element={<Email />} />
        </Route>
      )
    )
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
    reportWebVitals();
```

//////////////////////////
And here's my App.js file:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import Language from './screens/Language';
    import PreLoader from './components/PreLoader';

    function App() {

      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }, 3000);
      }, []);

      return (
        <div>
          {isLoading ? <PreLoader /> : <Language />}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

The button is in the Language component like this:
    `<div className="btn-container"><Link to='email'><button className="button">Continue</button>    </Link></div>`

I'm sure it's something obvious but I just can't find it.
Thanks in advance!

Clicking the button should render the Email component but it doesn't.  The web address changes to localhost:3000/email but the page remains the same (the Language component).

EDIT: I haven't included all code for the sake of brevity.   renders a splash screen and then the  component, which contains the button.  So it should go:

- Splash screen
- Language screen (language selection)
- Email screen (for email address input)
  Perhaps should add that this is an interview take-home test, and I'm out of my depth.

Comment: `App` isn't rendering an `Outlet` for the nested `"/email"` route to render content on, and I don't see any button you are referring to. Do you want the routes to be rendered independently, or as you have it with the email route nested? Can you [edit] to clarify the use case/UI?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese.  As per edit, out of my depth on an interview assignment so very likely missing things out of ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. The `App` component is missing rendering an `Outlet` component for the nested `"/email"` route to render its `element` content into.
2. The `Language` component is using a *relative* link target path instead of an *absolute* path. If the user is already on `"/email"` and the link/button is clicked again, the app will navigate *relative* to the current path and result in the URL path being `"/email/email"`, and so on. Absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` character, relative paths do not.

## Solution

Add an `Outlet` to `App` for the nest route:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Language from './screens/Language';
import PreLoader from './components/PreLoader';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? <PreLoader /> : <Language />}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you didn't intend for `Language` to be rendered at the same time as the `Email` component then you'll want to ***unnest*** the email route. This is to make each route/page independently matched and rendered.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="email" element={<Email />} />
    </>
  )
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Use an *absolute* link target path to the email page:

```
<div className="btn-container">
  <Link to="/email">
    <button className="button">Continue</button>
  </Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Drew Resse!  That's it working correctly.  I'd been tearing my hair out!  Very much appreciated.